# Javascript extend object's prototype but keep old prototype

Tags: javascript

I need to extend an object's prototype without removing it's current prototype

```
var obj = (function() {
    function Obj(){

    }

    Obj.prototype.func1 = function() {}

    extend = {
        func2: function(){}
    }

    Obj.prototype = extend;

    return Obj;
}());
```

How do I do this and keep `func1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as using a for-in loop to copy properties over from your existing `extend` object into `Obj.prototype`:

```
for (var key in extend)
    // make sure it's actually a direct property of extend
    if (extend.hasOwnProperty(key))
        // copy over value from extend into prototype
        Obj.prototype[key] = extend[key];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Obj.prototype.func2 = function() {}
```

... Just keep adding methods to the existing prototype.

Comment: But that's what I want to avoid

Comment: @php_nub_qq why? What is the problem you want to avoid? What's wrong with adding more functions to the prototype object?

Comment: @php_nub_qq Your post said "I need to extend an object's prototype without removing it's current prototype". That's what this does... It adds a method to the prototype without removing the current prototype or anything on it.

Comment: Because I keep repeating `Obj.prototype` and my functions may turn out to be a great number, that's just loss of space. I know I can put all functions in an object and then assign it to the prototype, but the question is more about the principle, why can't I extend the object like in `php` keeping all non-overwritten methods?

Comment: Your question was a bit unclear. You can, see the other answers. JavaScript uses prototype inheritance, not classical inheritance, so it's not easy to compare to languages that use classical inheritance. JavaScript has behavior delegation which is what allows the prototype system. It's actually very powerful and allows you to do some really nice OO stuff without trying to emulate classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "import" properties from another object, you can create an "extend" function:

```
function extend(o1, o2) {
  for (var key in o2)
    if (o2.hasOwnProperty(key))
      o1[key] = o2[key];
  return o1;
}
```

Then:

```
  extend(Obj.prototype, extend);
```